# When is multiplication by an element from a transformation group bijective?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am reading Allan Clark's *Elements of Abstract Algebra* and he states the following about transformation groups.

> We note that each $g \in G$ determines a one-to-one correspondence $g: X \to X$ given by $g(x) = g * x$ whose inverse is $g^{-1}: X \to X$.

Note that $G$ is the transformation group acting on $X$ and that Clark uses "one-to-one correspondence" in place of "bijective mapping".

Next, he defines:

> A transformation group $G$ acts *effectively* on $X$ iff for all $g, g * x = x; \forall x \in X \implies g = e$.

I actually have a question about this, too. Can anyone give a single example of a group transformation that's not effective? Please don't make it too complicated; I'm a beginner in group theory.

The main confusion is here:

> Show that the set $A(X)$ of one-to-one correspondences forms the largest effective group on $X$.

Didn't we say earlier that *every* transformation group is isomorphic to a set of one-to-one correspondences? How come now we're restricting ourselves to effective groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the *trivial group action*,  defined by $g\cdot x=x$ for every $x\in X$.  It's not effective.

For a less trivial example,  consider a non-trivial normal subgroup $H\triangleleft G$.  Let $G$ act on the group $G/H$, by left multiplication.   This won't be an effective action.   Any $h\in H$ fixes each coset.

Next, $A(x)=\rm{Sym}(X)$ is the symmetric group on $X$.  It consists in *all* the bijective maps from $X$ to itself.

A group action gives a homomorphism from $G$ to $\rm{Sym}(X)$.  If the action is effective (often called faithful) it's injective. Thus the largest group acting effectively on $X$ is $A(X)=\rm{Sym}(X)$.

---

Any group acts effectively on itself by left multiplication (or right multiplication by the inverse).

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is injective if the action is effective? Is it the homomorphism? Would it then be correct to say that the transformation group is isomorphic to a subset of $A(X)$ iff it is effective?

Comment: Right.   And because of my last comment,  we have Cayley's theorem,  which says every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group.